# Minimal normal subgroup and its centralizer.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ a finite group with $N$$\vartriangleleft$$G$ a minimal normal elementary abelian $p$-group. Suppose that $N$ is not self centralizing in $G$ but $C_G$($N$) is solvable ($p$ is a fixed prime divisor of $|G|$). Is it possible to find a normal abelian $p$-group $K$$\vartriangleleft$$G$ such that $N$$\lt$$K$ ? How can I do? Every kind of suggestion is appreciated! Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: If we allow $K=N$ then this is trivially true. If we are looking for $N < K$ then is $G = \mathbb Z_6$ and $N=2\mathbb Z_6$ a counterexample? There are no p-groups between $N$ and $G$. We know because there are no divisors of $|G|=6$ between $|N|=3$ and $|G|$ except for $6$ itself, and $\mathbb Z_6$ is not a p-group.

Comment: Sorry...I was wrong to ask the question...Excuse me.